# Penalties for "missing" Header tags

Tags: seo, headers

Running my site through Niel Patel's SEO Tester gives me multiple errors on `<h4>` elements being too short.

Thing is, the elements are too short (length = 0) because those headers are on a scrolling display banner, and will each only display for four seconds at a time.

Is there another way I should mark these headers? Should I just ignore these warnings

Comment: Ignore that tool. It is useless. You're wasting your time using it. Just write good contnet with headings that make sense for your users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strict rules about what should be in heading tags is an SEO strategy from five years ago.  Even then empty `<h4>` tags wouldn't have caused any SEO problems.   Google has long said that it doesn't penalize for poor HTML code, nor does it reward validating code.

These days Google is rendering pages to see the content.   I've seen evidence that it doesn't even matter if you use heading tags.  Styling a `<div>` or `<span>` with large bold text at the top of the page is just as good as using an `<h1>` for Google.